# Where do I find the code for built in Java Methods?

Tags: java, methods, built-in

I want to edit the Java method for replaceFirst. I know what it does and all, but I want to view the actual code. Thanks.

Comment: There's this site: http://grepcode.com/

Answer (score 0):

look in your jdk installation folder.there must be an src.zip. link this with your ide and you can browse the java source code as you browse you own. You xan extract the contents of the zip also and take a look.